# "Reject" button delets the original text after the changes made using Word API

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, office-addins, word-addins

I turn on the function "Track Changes" with the help of Word API. In the words found I add hyperlinks with the help of the following code:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = true;

if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Find.Execute
  (
      FindText: "link",
      MatchCase: true,
      Forward: true,
      MatchWildcards: true,
      Wrap: Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop
  )
)
{
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add(
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range, "https://www.google.ru/");
}
```

Then when I press the button "Review --> Reject", the whole word "link" gets deleted with the link, but not just the link that I've added. Why does that happen? How can it be fixed?

Comment: The same behavior is apparent in the Word UI, so this is not a programming question. It has nothing to do with your code - Word does the same thing if you add the hyperlink as a user. So the question is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you. It's just a question of the Word-Addins for the Stack Overflow, but I thought that this behavior is due to an error in the code.

Comment: Understandable, that you'd think that :-) At least you can feel good about the problem not being your fault!

Answer (score 0):

The same behavior is apparent in the Word UI.